# what cpp function in firefox gets invoked when javascript invokes clipboard.getData()?

Tags: javascript, c++, firefox

What C++ function is invoked in [Firefox source](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/) code when Javascript invokes [clipboard.getData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/getData) ?

My guess is [line 57 in MessageEvent::getData](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/dom/events/MessageEvent.cpp#l57)

But when I put a printf statement in there, it never gets hit.  Does anyone know which C++ function gets called in Firefox source when Javascript invokes clipboard.getData() ?

Comment: The code you include looks more like message event in service worker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DataTransfer::GetData](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/bfa4dfd40b8fe6f1a6504e86b5ad2c5fd402bfc0/dom/events/DataTransfer.cpp#339) is invoked.